# How to include header with namespace interface into c++/cli project with marshap_cppstd.h

Tags: c++, c++-cli, marshalling

I get several errors when trying to compile a c++/cli library that uses a native one and the c++/cli project includes msclr helpers for marshalling. If I add the following header

```
#include <msclr\marshal_cppstd.h>
```

i get the error

```
Error   1   error C2059: syntax error : '<class-head>'
```

and several others following up, too.

The syntax error points to the header file of an external (3rd party) c++ lib (so I can't change the header).

```
namespace SomeExternalLibNamespace
{
   namespace interface // problem might be here (interface is a keyword in c++/cli)
   {
```

If I don't include the marshal_cppstd.h and do the marshalling manually with own methods everything compiles and works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the external c++ library named a namespace ***interface***. This is a keyword in c++/cli. The visual studio parser/compiler of the c++/cli-wrapper for this lib gets broken when including the c++ headers of this lib (and the namespace called ***interface***) and including the headers for helpers e.g. in marshap_cppstd.h, too.

I wasn't able to solve that without doing the marshalling on my own instead of using the ms-helpers.

Answer (score 0):

My bad, didn't read it properly, if 'interface' is indeed a keyword, then that's the cause of the error obviously, try it with : namespace interface_ for example, and recompile to check the result then.

Comment: As I also wrote: "The syntax error points to the header file of an external c++ lib (so I can't change the header)."...

Answer (score -2):

you should use quotes : "" to include custom Header files :

```
#include "msclr\marshal_cppstd.h"
```

Comment: this does not solve the problem and is not a "custom" header, it is provided by microsoft